# Kile-beamer doesn't work, asks for pgf files one by one infinitely

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been using latex-beamer in kile since several years, never had any issues. Recently I started using that again in Ubuntu 18. Now, the kile asks for pgf files (pgfcore.sty,pgfkeys.code.tex.... ), one by one, infinitely!!  I downloaded 15 pgf files and kile continued to ask them. Do you know why this happens? How to avoid this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you installed the full TeX Live? If not, try to. You shouldn't be downloading these files manually.

Comment: Exactly how did you install latex on your Ubuntu? Just from Ubuntu? Then try installing `texlive-full`. The Ubuntu version of texlive is split into many Ubuntu packages (not really related to latex packages). By default Ubuntu (probably through your installation of kile) install a minimal Ubuntu texlive. Sadly it is rather hard to know which of the Ubuntu texlive packages to install so it is often easier to just install them all which is what installing  `texlive-full` will do. As TeXnician mentions you should never install/download these files by hand.